# D7 Why Doesn't My Javascript Fire When Admin Toolbar Is Loaded

Tags: javascript, toolbar

Probably a noob deal.

http://drupal.christmate.com

My custom theme has a simple JS attachment in the .info file like so:

```
scripts[] = jchwebdev.js
```

The code runs fine so long as no one is logged in, or so long as the logged in user is -not- the Admin. Actually, what I mean is that the code runs fine so long as the -toolbar- is not loaded.

In the Firebug Console I see this error (but again, only when the toolbar is displayed.)

```
TypeError: $.cookie is not a function

nodeName(j=Object[div#toolbar.toolbar], s=function(),  v=div#toolbar.toolbar)jquery.js?v=1.4.4 (line 34)

toArray(j=function(), s=undefined)jquery.js?v=1.4.4 (line 27)

once(id="toolbar", fn=function())jquery...s?v=1.2 (line 55)

attach(context=Document config)toolbar.js?mnxwdq (line 12)

(?)()drupal.js?mnxwdq (line 55)

nodeName(j=Object { overlayParent={...}, contextualLinks={...}, initColorbox={...}, more...}, s=function(), v=undefined)jquery.js?v=1.4.4 (line 34)

attachBehaviors(context=Document config, settings=Object { basePath="/", ajaxPageState={...}, colorbox={...}, more...})drupal.js?mnxwdq (line 53)

(?)()drupal.js?mnxwdq (line 391)

noConflict(j=function())jquery.js?v=1.4.4 (line 30)
inArray()jquery.js?v=1.4.4 (line 38)
[Break On This Error]   
var collapsed = $.cookie('Drupal.toolbar.collapsed');
```

So I'm assuming that I have an error in my little JS module because when I remove that JS the console error goes away. But I can't figure out why the two are related?

THANKS!

Below is the source JS:

```
        (function ($) {
            Drupal.behaviors.myfunction = {
                attach: function (context, settings) {

        //Start of xfadeshow

                $.fn.extend({

                jchSlider: function(options) {
                     //Set the default values, use comma to separate the settings, example:

                    var defaults = {
                            padding: 20,
                            delayTime: 7000,
                            func : {}
                    }

                    var options =  jQuery.extend(defaults, options);

                    return this.each(function() {
                         var o = options;   

                    var slider = jQuery(this);
                    var lSlider = slider.children().size();         
                    var sliderID = jQuery(slider).attr('id');
                    var selector = jQuery(this).next();
                    var selectorID = jQuery(slider).attr('id');
                    var animationType = jQuery(slider).hasClass("fade");

                    var play;
                    var jQueryactive = jQuery(selector).children('li:first');
                    var jQuerysactive  = jQuery(slider).children('li:first');       
                    var maxh = 0;

                    jQuery(slider).children().hide();

                    // alert( jQuery(slider).html() );
                    jQueryactive.addClass("active");
                    jQuerysactive.addClass("active")
                    jQuerysactive.show();

                    jQuery(slider).children().each(function(i) {
                            i++;
                            maxh = Math.max(maxh, jQuery(this).height());           
                        });

                        jQuery(slider).css('height', maxh);

                        jQuery(selector).children().click(function(e) {
                            jQueryactive  = jQuery(this);

                            //alert(e);
                            //normally there is no <a> required. Click on li to navigate
                            // if clicked on an <a> link inside the slideshow
                            if( jQuery(e.target).prop('tagName') == 'A' )
                                {
                                return true;
                                }

                            var inD = jQuery('#selector li').index(this);               
                            jQuerysactive = jQuery('#slideshow > li:eq(' + inD + ')' );

                            //Reset Timer
                            clearInterval(play); //Stop the rotation
                            slideShow(); //Trigger rotation immediately
                            slideSwitch(); // Resume rotation
                            return false;
                        });


                     //On Hover
                     jQuery(slider).children('> li').hover( function() {
                             clearInterval(play); //Stop the rotation
                     }, function() {
                            jQueryactive = jQuery(selector).children('li.active').next();
                            jQuerysactive = jQuery(slider).children('li.active').next(); //go back to first                                         
                                    if ( jQueryactive.length === 0) { //If paging reaches the end...
                                        jQueryactive = jQuery(selector).children('li:first'); //go back to first
                                        jQuerysactive = jQuery(slider).children('li:first'); //go back to first                     
                                    }
                            slideShow(); //Trigger rotation immediately
                            slideSwitch(); // Resume rotation
                     });    

                     var slideSwitch = function( func ) {
                            // alert( typeof func);              
                            if( typeof func == 'function'  ) {
                                inD = jQueryactive.index();
                            // alert('inD-SW ' + inD);
                                func(inD);
                            }

        //                  sCurrentIndex = jQueryactive.index();
        //                  if( sCurrentIndex = lSlider-1)


                            jQuery(selector).children().removeClass('active'); //Remove all active class
                            jQuery(slider).children().removeClass('active'); //Remove all active class
                            jQuery(slider).children().hide();
                            jQueryactive.addClass('active');
                            jQuerysactive.addClass('active');
                            if(animationType)
                                jQuerysactive.fadeIn(1200);
                            else
                                jQuerysactive.show(500);                
                     };

                        //Rotation + Timing Event
                     var slideShow = function(){        
                            play = setInterval(function(){ //Set timer - this will repeat itself every 3 seconds
                            jQueryactive = jQueryactive.next();
                            jQuerysactive = jQuerysactive.next(); //go back to first                                            
                            if ( jQueryactive.length === 0) { //If paging reaches the end...
                                jQueryactive = jQuery(selector).children('li:first'); //go back to first
                                jQuerysactive = jQuery(slider).children('li:first'); //go back to first                     
                            }
                            slideSwitch(o.func);}, o.delayTime); //Timer speed in milliseconds (3 seconds)
                     };

                     slideShow();               

                    });     

             }    // options


             });  // extends


        //End of slideshow
            jQuery('#slideshow-wrapper').jchSlider();   
            jQuery('#home-slideshow').jchSlider({delayTime: 4000, func: function(inD){ 
                 if(inD==6) jQuery('#top_slogan').css('opacity',0); else jQuery('#top_slogan').css('opacity',1);                                                                                                                                              // if(inD==7) jQuery('#get_started').show(); else jQuery('#get_started').hide(); 
                 }
             });            

        // don't touch anything below here
             }
        };
        })(jQuery);
```

Comment: Are you using the contrib [Admin Menu](https://drupal.org/project/admin_menu) or the default toolbar? Can you provide a link or the html within `#slideshow-wrapper` & `#home-slideshow` so that I can test it?  Also, can you confirm that toolbar.js is being attached (Trying to figure out if only the library is missing or all of the toolbar module attachments).

Comment: The default toolbar. I just added the URL: http://drupal.christmate.com. -My- JS -is- being loaded, but the console gives an error with the -cookie- from the toolbar which makes me think there's something in my function drupal dislikes. You won't see the error though, since you're not the Admin.

Comment: I'll look at it more later, but I was able to copy your html,css, and js, throw in some dummy images and it works fine for me with the core toolbar enabled.  What version of jQuery?